# why graph.degree returns less values than number of nodes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a graph in Spark using Graphx like:

```
val graph = Graph(users, rels)
println("number of vertices is " + graph.numVertices + " and number of edges is " + graph.numEdges)
```

and the result is:

> number of vertices is 253 and number of edges is 228

I then .cache() the network and run:

```
val degrees = graph.degrees
// debug
println("done with degrees, I have " + degrees.count() + " degree values")
```

I end up having:

> done with degrees, I have 112 degree values

So my question is: is there a reason why I don't have a degree result for every node in the graph?

Comment: A verifiable example would great.

Comment: Cannot share the dataset... But I understand correctly that degrees is supposed to report all nodes, even those with degree = 0?

Comment: I didn't mean your real dataset :) No, it doesn't report nodes with zero degree. I guess this is the source of the problem.

Comment: Yes that is the problem...  So my problem is to map 0 for nodes that are not reported in degrees....